# Votes count on Close Votes

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

While reviewing the closed questions I couldn't figure out what the count of votes for each category. For example I need to know the count on the question that is "Not constructive", "Too localized", "Not a real question".

I can't see this count in the banner. Any approach to improve readability? How could I achieve this information with the minimal effort?

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't figure out what the count of votes for each category

Use the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203775/questions-with-pending-close-votes) for unclear what your asking (*103*). For too broad type *104*, primarily opinion based type *105*..

Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201658/questions-with-pending-close-votes-off-topic-reasons) for off-topic reasons. General computing software/hardware type *4*, for tool/off-site resource type *8*.

The number of results/rows returned for each query is the number of questions that currently have at least 1 close vote on them.